# Website under huge traffic PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, caching

Let me show what problem I'm dealing with:

1. website powered by Apache 2.2 + PHP 5.x + MySQL 5.1.x
2. peak traffic = 2.000 unique visitors/min  =  5-8k pageviews/min
3. normal traffic = 2.000 unique visitors/day

   - website works well while under normal traffic
   - website lags while under peak traffic
   - my server cpu load is pretty big while under peak traffic (because of mysql/php processes), so my website is lagging.

**Normal state:** server response in 0.1-0.4 sec/pageview. PHP code is optimized to get and process all data from database and output HTML code within this time (call it server-response).

**Peak traffic state:** server response in 2-5 sec/pageview. And that's a bit longer response than I'm happy with. I don't want my visitors to wait so long for requested page.

**What I'm doing now:** My way to deal with this problem now is local cache system. I'm making local cache file (stored on disk) for about 10 minutes with cached SQL results - so I don't have to call the same sql query with every request.

My website is http://www.lechaton.cz/.

Is there any better way how to deal with peak traffic or optimize CPU utilization?

Comment: Maybe skip the apache part :) like [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) does. Ofcourse this depends on your host.

Comment: Is the increased traffic wanted traffic, or is it caused by a malfunctioning search engine/(D)Dos attack? I've seen both, and it might be a good idea to check that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: 1. find out what makes your site lag. Database cannot handle traffic? not enough memory for your processes? problem with concurrency, so people need to wait for each other? 2. give us some relevant information about that specific problem after you've identified it. What code could be the problem of the concurrency issue, is your databaseserver big enough // what processes use your memory, etc? maybe you want to server your static content with nginx, maybe you need a memcached sollution, maybe different programming...

Comment: 1: no, sometimes there is some tv ad or tv show what makes this kind of traffic

Comment: I think mysql cant handle the number of concurent queries. every query consumes some cpu time. I've set concurency to 300 concurent connections - every request is served, but with a bit lag. Server has 16G RAM.

Comment: Add in a microsecond timer for each part of a page, and see what takes the longest to generate. It's usually the database queries, of course. By how much did the HTML cache approach work? That's the first thing I would do.

Comment: I just saw this article that came out a few days ago discussing scaling PHP applications, it may be helpful to you - http://keyholesoftware.com/2013/11/18/intro-to-scaling-php-part1/

Comment: You misunderstood: even when an ad increases traffic, there is still a reason why you are slow. Like you say, maybe concurrent queries? but you only can know that if you test. Do **not** start thinking about sollutions without testing _what_ is the problem.

Comment: First off - thank all for the support!! I'm not asking without testing and without solution. I have solution - my cache. Cache works well. But I'm asking if there is anything better or more sophisticated..? If you're interested in time log - meaning server responses - view this: http://www.lechaton.cz/assets/time.log it's not bad, but you can find there responses e.g. 5sec+

Comment: (I don't blame you for the huge traffic. Shows that semi-naked pictures of good looking women still reign supreme on the 'Net).  Also look at the Apache zip extension; look at setting the Expires tag in the HTML header; install apachetop; save your images to disk not the database

Comment: :) yes, nice women = huge traffic. I'm using mod_expires, images stored on disk, imagecache (after some php-gd2 image quality conversions and thumbs resize). Thanks for apachetop hint - I have to try it for better monitoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks all for your time and advise!**

I've been working through whole weekend and testing and testing and comparing methods and solutions.

**Nginx solution (replace LAMP with LNMP)**

- I'm still using Apache2.2, but even using nginx (thanks to  [Bondye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1293244/bondye)) there is not a big difference.
- I've tried LNMP on debian wheezy, but with not a big difference from LAMP.
- For static files nginx is faster in fact.
- Nginx with PHP-FPM is a twice faster, that could be solution for some cases, but not solving my issues for 100%.

**Tune-up your MySQL settings and MySQL queries**

- Tune-up your MySQL server with better caching and buffering. Also check your max-connections and memory usage.
- But the most important is to optimize your queries for best performance. Even if your queries are best performing with mysql-cache, bigger traffic brings your server down within several minutes of big traffic. **YOU HAVE TO CACHE** your output!!

**Tune-up apache**

- tune up your apache mpm-prefork
- Reduce KeepAliveTimeout to max 5 seconds (default=30)
- keep maxClients set to correct number (depends on your RAM, max-processes and max-servers in settings directive)

### **Final conclusion**

**1) content cache = rule #1**
I've found the best solution is: **cache as much as much content as you can**. There is no reason why every user should generate same output  if there is option to display cached content. It's much faster and it saves your resources.

**2) nginx for static content**
You can use nginx to perform best with static files and content, there is much lower cpu load with multiple processes.

With PHP-FPM your code speeds up twice (maybe a bit more). But I can't consider it as final solution.

**3) test your website with benchmark tools** I've used siege and apache benchmark (ab) and mysqlslap.

These steps helped me to reduce CPU load with my brand new server, speed up my server-response and balance my peak-traffic during big events.

Hope someone will find it helpful.

Comment: You could do so much better. Use varnish to cache the dynamic pages for 1~5 min (whatever duration you are comfortable with) You wouldn't even be compiling php anymore, it would be like serving static html, but for 1 min, then the content gets refreshed.